# Send email with every item in list as body

Tags: 2010, list, workflow

I need a List Workflow that will send an email to UserX, with the email body consisting of information from every item in the list that the Workflow is associated to. Based on the actions provided in SharePoint Designer I haven't seen a way to do this.

Side Note: As a .NET developer I'm comfortable with any alternative/custom suggestions to do this.

Comment: use rest in declarative workflow 2013.

Comment: @I-touch Is that something I will have access to using SharePoint 2010? Or is that specific to SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Call HTTP Web Service` to get all data u need, than loop for all items in dictionary you get back and store it in variable. Than put this variable to the body of email.

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListName')/items?$select=ID,Priority&$filter=Priority%20eq%20'High
```